# How can pass array argument into Selected Attribute of JQuery ComboTree in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I am using Jquery ComboTree in my html . I am trying to pass value from an array variable into the  Selected Attribute of Jquery ComboTree as an array. The variable `defaultSelected` contained the following data. I have to pass into selected attribute as an array `selected: [defaultSelected]`.
`defaultSelected` is an  array(6)

```
0:1.1
1:1.2
2:1.3
3:2.1
4:2.2
5:1
6:2
```

```js
 FillSalaryDepotsMappings(@ViewBag.DepotLocationMappingForSalary);
    function FillSalaryDepotsMappings(defaultSelected) {
            console.log(defaultSelected);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/User/GetDepotDepartemntsForMap",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                     $('#ddlSalaryMapping').comboTree({
                        source: data,
                        isMultiple: true,
                        cascadeSelect: true,
                        collapse: true,
                        selected: [defaultSelected] // Here I have to pass the argument value
                    });
                    // $("#hfSalaryMapping").val(defaultSelected);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }

            });

        }
```

```html
<div class="controls col-sm-9">
                                        <input type="text" id="ddlSalaryMapping" placeholder="Select" />
                                        <input type="hidden" id="hfSalaryMapping" asp-for="SelectedSalaryMapping" />
                                    </div>
```

User Model

```
[NotMapped]
 public string SelectedSalaryMapping { get; set; }
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks Alan

Comment: If `defaultSelected` is already an array why do you need to pass it with `[defaultSelected]` just `selected: defaultSelected`?

Comment: I tried that way, then it will not work   in line ("#hfSalaryMapping").val(defaultSelected);. The newly selected records will not be updated to the hidden  inputbox "#hfSalaryMapping"

Answer (score 0):

You can add a onchange function in your javascripts.Below is an example.

```
<form  asp-action="GetCombo">
<input type="text" id="example" placeholder="Select">
<input type="hidden" id="hfSalaryMapping" asp-for="SelectedSalaryMapping" />
<input type="submit" value="click"/>
</form>

@section Scripts
{
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="~/js/comboTreePlugin.js"></script>

<script>
    var ar = [1.1, 1.2];
    var myData = [
        {
            id: 0,
            title: 'Item 1 '
        }, {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Item 2',
            subs: [
                 {
                    id: 1.1,
                    title: 'Item 2-1'
                }, {
                    id: 1.2,
                    title: 'Item 2-2'
                }, {
                    id: 1.3,
                    title: 'Item 2-3'
                }
            ]
        }, {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Item 3'
        },
    ];
    $(document).ready(function () {
        comboTree3 = $('#example').comboTree({
            source: myData,
            isMultiple: true,
            selected: ar
        });
        $('#hfSalaryMapping').val(ar);
        comboTree3.onChange(function () {
            console.log(String(comboTree3.getSelectedIds()));
            $('#hfSalaryMapping').val(String(comboTree3.getSelectedIds()));
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: Hi Yinqiu, Please can you guide me , how can I call GetDepotDepartemntsForMap  using Ajax method